# configuring the urls.py gives problem in the url generation

Tags: django

I have an application running django 3.1. I do have problems with the urls. I guess there is either a problem with the urls.py or in my asociated view.
In my application, the view (fil main.py) is called "main".
If I go the the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/, I see a correct rendering of the view.
My view includes a button to click on. When I click, the url is now: http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/main/ which is an error (404 page not found).

My url.py is:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import re_path
from django.views.static import serve

from . import main

urlpatterns = [
    path('main/', main.main, name='main'),
    path('', main.main, name='main'),
]
```

My view uses the following:

```
return render(request,'main.html')
```

I must add that this is my first dango project. I've tried to look into the django documentation first, and tried various changes in my urls.py... No success so far.

Thanks.

S/

Comment: What does your **project/urls.py** look like?

Comment: thanks @Mugoma. Here it is. oxybom is the application name in my project.

`urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('', include('oxybom.urls')),
]`

Answer (score 0):

In order to visit `.../main/**main**/` you will need to add it to your urlpatterns like so:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('main/**main**/', views.my_view_function, name='star-main')
]
```

The first argument to `paths` is the url you want to visit, the second argument is the view function (or class) responsible for handling the logic when visiting this url, the third argument is the shortcut name you would use in your templates (and elsewhere) to reference this particular url.

Side note - two of your urlpatterns have the same name (`main`) - not sure if this will throw an error but it certianly will cause problems!

Comment: If I do this, it does not solve the problem. The next url is: ../main/main/main/ which gives a new error. I don't uderstand why a "main" is added. Furthermore, as a consequence, the context is not saved.

Comment: The problem is not in your `urls.py`, its in your template - how is your button redirecting users? You keep appending `main` to your url pattern.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. I guess you're right indeed. my form is the following: <form action="main/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">. I guess I need to get rid of the action attribute..

Comment: You can also try using the url tag like so: `action="{% url 'main' %}"` - however , `main` is the name of two of your urls - you need to give them unique names or you may get unwanted behavior.

Comment: Yes, it works the same. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Then there is no path to handle  http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/main/

The paths in your project are

> /

> /main/

If you need to handle your path above , you could:
**project/urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [     
    ...
    path('main/', include('oxybom.urls')), 
]
```

or

**app/urls.py**

```py
...
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('main/main/', main.main, name='main'),
]
```

Comment: In fact, I don't want the url to be constructed that way. I'd like it to stay either  http://127.0.0.1:8000/main or  http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and the context saved.

Comment: The issue then is with your html. Please include it